# Proving that $f$ verifies $f(1−x) + f(x) = 1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, products

I have a function which is defined for $x \in (0,1)$ and for $p>1$ with the expression

\begin{align*} 
f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \frac{(-1)^{p+k}}{(p-1-k)!(p+k)!}\left(\prod_{i=k-p+1, i\neq0}^{k+p} (x+k-i)\right) 
\end{align*}

I would like to show that $f(1-x) + f(x) = 1$.

### **What I have done so far**

With a little bit of algebra I have

\begin{align*} 
f(x) 
&= \frac{1}{(2p-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} (-1)^{p+k} \binom{2p-1}{p+k} \left(\prod_{i=k-p+1, i\neq0}^{k+p} (x+k-i)\right)
&& \text{using }\binom{n}{m} = \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}
\\
&= \frac{1}{(2p-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} (-1)^{p+k} \binom{2p-1}{p+k} \left(\prod_{j=1-p, j\neq-k}^{p} (x-j)\right) 
&& \text{using the change of indices j=i-k} 
\\
&= \frac{1}{(2p-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} (-1)^{p+k} \binom{2p-1}{p+k} \left(\prod_{j=1-p}^{p} (x-j)\right) \frac{1}{x+k}
&& \text{completing the product} 
\\
&= \frac{1}{(2p-1)!} \left(\prod_{j=1-p}^{p} (x-j)\right) \left(\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\frac{(-1)^{p+k}}{x+k}\binom{2p-1}{p+k}\right)
&& \text{factoring the product from the sum} 
\end{align*}

Then I introduce the functions
\begin{align*} 
F(x) &= (2p-1)! f(x)  = G(x) H(x)\\
G(x) &= \prod_{j=1-p}^{p} (x-j) \\
H(x) &= \sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\frac{(-1)^{p+k}}{x+k}\binom{2p-1}{p+k}
\end{align*}

So the initial question reduces to proving that $F(1-x) + F(x) = (2p-1)!$

Next, playing with the indices of the product I have been able to show that $G(1-x) = G(x)$.

So that now I only need to show $G(x) \left( H(1-x) + H(x)\right) = (2p-1)!$

### **EDIT:**

I have just been able to simplify $H(1-x) + H(x)$ as follows :

\begin{align*} 
H(x) 
&=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\frac{(-1)^{p+k}}{x+k}\binom{2p-1}{p+k} 
\\
&=\sum_{s=p}^{2p-1}\frac{(-1)^{s}}{x-p+s}\binom{2p-1}{s}
&& \text{using a change of index } s=p+k 
\end{align*}

And

\begin{align*} 
H(1-x) 
&=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\frac{(-1)^{p+k}}{1-x+k}\binom{2p-1}{p+k} 
\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\frac{(-1)^{p+k}}{1-x+k}\binom{2p-1}{p-1-k}
&& \text{using } \binom{2p-1}{p+k} = \binom{2p-1}{p-1-k} 
\\
&=\sum_{s=0}^{p-1}\frac{(-1)^{s}}{x-p+s}\binom{2p-1}{s}
&& \text{using a change of index } s=p-1-k 
\end{align*}

So finally

\begin{align*} 
H(1-x) + H(x) 
&=\sum_{s=0}^{2p-1}\frac{(-1)^{s}}{x-p+s}\binom{2p-1}{s}
\end{align*}

### **EDIT2:**

I have just made the same work on $G(x)$ as follows

\begin{align*} 
G(x) 
&=\prod_{j=1-p}^{p} (x-j) \\
&=\prod_{s=0}^{2p-1} (x-p+s)
&& \text{using a change of index } s=p-i 
\end{align*}

---

Now I think the constant $(2p-1)!$ in the relation $F(1-x)+F(x)=(2p-1)!$ comes from the binomial factor in $H(1-x) + H(x)$ but I don't see how to prove that...

Any lead ?

Answer (score 1):

I have actually found a way to solve the question from **EDIT1** and **EDIT2**
So

\begin{align*} 
F(1-x) + F(x)
&= G(x) \Big( H(1-x) + H(x) \Big) \\
&= \Bigg(\prod_{s=0}^{2p-1}(x-p+s)\Bigg)\Bigg(\sum_{k=0}^{2p-1}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{x-p+k}\binom{2p-1}{k}\Bigg)\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{2p-1} (-1)^{k}\binom{2p-1}{k}\Bigg(\prod_{s=0, s \neq k}^{2p-1}(x-p+s)\Bigg)
\end{align*}

This the (2p-1)-th order finite difference scheme with step $h=1$ applied to the function

\begin{align*} 
g(x) = \Bigg( \prod_{s=0, s \neq k}^{2p-1}(x-p) \Bigg) = (x-p)^{2p-1}
\end{align*}

So clearly this would mean that :

\begin{align*} 
F(1-x) + F(x) 
&= \Delta_{h}^{2p-1} (x-p)^{2p-1} \\
&= \frac{d^{2p-1}}{dx^{2p-1}} (x-p)^{2p-1} \\
&= (2p-1)!
\end{align*}

### Hot point to justify in the conclusion :

So we just need now to justify the passage from $\Delta_{h}^{2p-1}(x-p)^{2p-1}$ to $\frac{d^{2p-1}}{dx^{2p-1}} (x-p)^{2p-1}$.

Is there a property that says the nth-order finite difference scheme is exact on polynomials ?

### Found a justification here :

https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01350976/file/on_the_link_between_finite_difference_and_derivative_of_polynomials_kolosov_petro_2017.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Here we have a *[partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Procedure)* in disguise.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{f(x)}&=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\frac{(-1)^{p+k}}{(p-1-k)!(p+k)!}
> \prod_{\substack{j=k-p+1\\j\neq 0}}^{k+p}(x+k-j)\\
> &=\prod_{j=-p+1}^{p}(x-j)\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}
> \frac{(-1)^{p+k}}{(p-1-k)!(p+k)!}\,\frac{1}{x+k}\tag{1}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\prod_{j=-p}^{p-1}(x+j)\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}
> \frac{(-1)^{p+k}}{(p-1-k)!(p+k)!}\,\frac{1}{x+k}}\tag{2}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we expand the summands with $(x+k)/(x+k)$ and shift the product by $k$ to start with $j=-p+1$. This way the product can be factored out from the sum.
- In (2) we substitute $j$ with $-j$ in the product.

> We start with (2) and consider $f(1-x)$. We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{f(1-x)}&=\prod_{j=-p}^{p-1}(1-x+j)\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}
> \frac{(-1)^{p+k}}{(p-1-k)!(p+k)!}\,\frac{1}{1-x+k}\\
> &=\prod_{j=-p}^{p-1}(x-j-1)\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}
> \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k!(2p-1-k)!}\,\frac{1}{-x+p-k}\tag{3}\\
> &=\prod_{j=-p+1}^{p}(x+j-1)\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}
> \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!(2p-1-k)!}\,\frac{1}{x+k-p}\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\prod_{j=-p}^{p-1}(x+j)\sum_{k=-p}^{-1}
> \frac{(-1)^{p+k}}{(p+k)!(p-1-k)!}\,\frac{1}{x+k}}\tag{5}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (3) we factor out $(-1)^{2p}=1$ from the product. We also change the order of summation $k\to p-1-k$.
- In (4) we substitute $j$ with $-j$ in the product and we expand numerator and denominator of the summands with $-1$.
- In (5) we shift the index $j$ by one to start with $j=-p$. We also shift the index $k$ by $p$ to start with $k=-p$.

> We can now sum up (2) and (5) and get
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{f(x)+f(1-x)}&\color{blue}{=\prod_{j=-p}^{p-1}(x+j)\sum_{k=-p}^{p-1}
> \frac{(-1)^{p+k}}{(p+k)!(p-1-k)!}\,\frac{1}{x+k}}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}

The right-hand side of (6) looks like a *partial fraction decomposition*. Indeed, we consider a function
\begin{align*}
g(x)=\frac{1}{\prod_{j=-p}^{p-1}(x+j)}
\end{align*}
The function $g(x)$ is a rational function with $2p$ pairwise different simple poles. Therefore we can find a representation
\begin{align*}
g(x)=\frac{1}{\prod_{j=-p}^{p-1}(x+j)}=\sum_{k=-p}^{p-1}\frac{a_k}{x+k}\qquad\qquad a_k\in\mathbb{R}
\end{align*}

Multiplication with the denominator of $g(x)$ gives
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{1=\prod_{j=-p}^{p-1}(x+j)\sum_{k=-p}^{p-1}\frac{a_k}{x+k}}\tag{7}
\end{align*}

> We can now evaluate (7) at $x=-k_0, -p\leq k_0\leq p-1$. We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> 1&=\left.\prod_{j=-p}^{p-1}(x+j)\sum_{k=-p}^{p-1}\frac{a_k}{x+k}\right|_{x=-k_0}\\
> &=\prod_{\substack{j=-p\\j\neq k_0}}^{p-1}\left(-k_0+j\right)a_{k_0}\\
> a_{k_0}&=\frac{1}{\prod_{\substack{j=-p\\j\neq k_0}}^{p-1}(j-k_0)}\\
> &=\frac{1}{\prod_{j=-p}^{k_0-1}(j-k_0)}\,\frac{1}{\prod_{j=k_0+1}^{p-1}(j-k_0)}\\
> &=\frac{(-1)^{p+k_0}}{(p+k_0)!}\,\frac{1}{\left(p-1-k_0\right)!}
> \end{align*}
> The coefficients $a_{k_0}$ can now be put into (7) and we obtain expression (6). We conclude
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{f(x)+f(1-x)=1}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.